# Azure SQL Pool what really it is and could it be used for Postgres database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have question regarding `SQL Pool`. Not sure i understood what it is. Does `SQL Pool` service is the service for `SQL Server` type databases? I have `Postgres` database and consider to move it to `Azure` nevertheless what is there any usage of `SQL Pool` service in case of `Azure Postgres` or it's only for `Azure SQL Server`  database? Last: Does `SQL Pool` also used by Synapse ETL?

Comment: SQL Pools should only be used for Synapse - they are way too expensive to have them running 24/7. If you need a permanent SQL Server, you should use Azure SQL instance.

Comment: @Filburt within SQL Pool i can create only databases which are SQL Server (tsql) related? Can i also use Postgres database there or not?

Comment: No, Postgresql database can't be deployed in SQL pool. You can deploy on premises PostgreSQL to Azure DB for PostgreSQL. find tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-postgresql-azure-postgresql-online)

Comment: But i could writer the sam way as in sql server like store procedure etc when i created any database in sql pool right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Azure SQL Pool is used with Azure Synapse Analytics to query Big Data.** You can consider it as a Data Warehouse. Once your dedicated SQL pool is created, you can import big data with simple PolyBase T-SQL queries, and then use the power of the distributed query engine to run high-performance analytics.

**How SQL Pool works?** In a cloud data solution, data is ingested into big data stores from a variety of sources. Once in a big data store, Hadoop, Spark, and machine learning algorithms prepare and train the data. When the data is ready for complex analysis, dedicated SQL pool uses PolyBase to query the big data stores. PolyBase uses standard T-SQL queries to bring the data into dedicated SQL pool tables.

**No, PostgreSQL can't be used in SQL Pool.** There is actually no link between these two services. If you want to migrate the on-premises PostgreSQL to Azure, you can use Azure Database for PostgreSQL. Check [Tutorial: Migrate PostgreSQL to Azure DB for PostgreSQL online using DMS via the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-postgresql-azure-postgresql-online).

Comment: Ok I see so mens sql pool is simply speaking i could created databases in it of type sql server which mens coding part is tsql line in sql server right? I mens store procedures, tables are line for sql server?

Comment: Are you talking about Dedicated SQL pool or SQL elastic pool? I posted my answer for Dedicated SQL Pool which is used by Synapse.

Comment: What's the diffrwnce between both?

Comment: Dedicated SQL pool is used for big data using Synapse Analytics. Elastic pool is a collection of multiple Azure SQL Database with shared computing environment. check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/455253/what-is-the-difference-between-elastic-pools-and-s.html)

Comment: Ya but it's still tsql i mean the same way i do e.g store procedures, SQL etc.. if I would be on regularnie sql server ?

Comment: Yes, it is TSQL only.